# Unresolved reference: bundleOf

Tags: android, kotlin

After updating some dependencies(not sure which one, but it includes navigation-ktx and fragment-ktx), "bundleOf" disappeared. Was it deleted? Autocomplete suggests me only "persistableBundleOf()", but it's not what I need.
P.S. I have "implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2'" too.
UPD: My build.gradle:

```
implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.3.1'

implementation 'androidx.preference:preference-ktx:1.1.1'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'

def navigation_version = "2.3.4"
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$navigation_version"
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$navigation_version"
```

Comment: Its `import androidx.core.os.bundleOf` .. have you tried it ? if its not working add relevent dependencies with question .

Comment: @ADM Yes, it exists in import, but "bundleOf" highlighted in red. I updated my post with gradle-dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Use:
import androidx.core.os.bundleOf

...and this in gradle dependencies:
implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.12.0") //use latest